Laravel Str::orderedUuid() vs uuid 7
Laravel has a Str::orderedUuid() method that the trait HasUuids uses by default. I understand that uuids from this method can be sorted lexicographically and it helps databases indexation.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

By default, The HasUuids trait will generate "ordered" UUIDs for your models. These UUIDs are more efficient for indexed database storage because they can be sorted lexicographically.

Why Laravel does not use UUID v7 (e.g. Str::uuid7()) which is also timestamp based and can be can be sorted lexicographically based on my understanding of the Symfony documentation about UUIDs ?

Laravel's Str::orderedUuid() function has existed since 2018(Laravel v5.6) originally trying to fix problems with UUID v4. More details on Str::orderedUuid implementation can be found in this blog post.
In contrast, UUID v7 is also relatively recently introduced to reach similar goals. But keep in mind that UUID v7 has been made a standard only this year with the publication of RFC 9562 in May 2024.
So to answer your question on why Laravel HasUuids preferred its own implementation could simply be that it predates v7 becoming the standard.
Like always to still give you flexibility, Laravel v11 gives you the trait Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasVersion7Uuids as another answer also suggested which lets you use the new standard without breaking existing code bases.
I would like you to note that both are timestamp-based and both are lexicographically ordered and for general use cases are similar in use, the difference being one is a standard now and the other is not.


Why Laravel does not use UUID v7 (e.g. Str::uuid7())...

I don't know which version you are using but Laravel-11 use it. You need to modify your model to use the HasVersion7Uuids trait. This trait will automatically generate a version-7 UUID when a new model is created.
You need to import and use this trait Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasVersion7Uuids;.In that trait this newUniqueId() method generate and retunr a new UUID (version 7) for the model.
For detailed information check this Laravel-11 API documentation link.
Also check this link.

Thank you. I guess the documentation is incomplete because it recommends the HasUuids. Is HasVersion7Uuids the new recommended way ?

@magrigry, It depends.HasUuids is not time related where HasVersion7Uuids is time ordered UUID.So use HasVersion7Uuids when you need to generate time ordered UUID. As you know default one in laravel is HasUuids, so when you need a UUID that reflect the time order of their creation then use HasVersion7Uuids.

The documentation of the method Str::orderedUuid() (used by the HasUuids trait) claims that it Generate a time-ordered UUID. Why HasUuidswouldn't be time related then ?

Yes that is correct, but there is another point that is HasUuid is version 4 if I am not wrong but reaming one is of version 7 as it's name implies. So there might be some more upgradation in version 7 that currently I don't know , I need to research about it.

Both are time-ordered and lexicographically ordered, I have provided more details in my answer.
